# Moodle: core_user_get_users_by_field return a blank array

Tags: moodle

I've configured a webservice in a production website, but when I do a call to core_user_get_users_by_field function this returns a blank array except for the webservice user/role.

What permissions or things  I must configure to get the right information for all users?

Best regards.

Comment: How and where are you invoking the call to the core_user_get_users_by_field function?

Answer (score 2):

To allow the webservice user to see profiles other than it's own you need to grant it

```
moodle/site:viewuseridentity
```

To allow the webservice user to see the user's full profile you need to grant it

```
moodle/user:viewalldetails
```